# Mix_PlayMusic causing memory corruption

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2, memory-corruption

I've been having trouble with a game I've been working on, where once I added music it started segfaulting in my frequently-called texture-loading code, between 5-30 secs after it started playing. The best I could come up with was that it is some sort of memory corruption. After a good week of unsuccessfully trying to debug it (trying things like GFlags pageheap), I managed to cut it down to the following code, which still exhibits the problem.

Sometimes this segfaults with the callstack going through `SDL2_mixer.dll`, but mostly it occurs in the `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface` call, due to the renderer being in a bad state. numTextures gets to between 15000-40000 on my machine (Windows 10 x64, with program compiled for x86).

My gut tells me that there's an issue in my environment or code, rather than an issue in SDL itself, but I'm at a loss. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_mixer.h>
#include <cassert>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    assert(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0);

    SDL_Window * pWindow_ = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480, 0x0);
    assert(pWindow_ != nullptr);

    SDL_Renderer * pRenderer_ = SDL_CreateRenderer(pWindow_, -1, 0);
    assert(pRenderer_ != nullptr);

    assert(Mix_OpenAudio(44100, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 512) == 0);

    Mix_Music * pMusic = Mix_LoadMUS("sounds/tranquility.wav");
    assert(pMusic != nullptr);
    assert(Mix_PlayMusic(pMusic, -1) == 0);

    SDL_Surface * pSurface = IMG_Load("images/caution.png");
    assert(pSurface != nullptr);
    SDL_Texture * pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer_, pSurface);
    assert(pTexture != nullptr);

    int numTextures = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        numTextures += 10;
        assert(pTexture != nullptr);
        SDL_DestroyTexture(pTexture);
        pTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(pRenderer_, pSurface);
        assert(pTexture != nullptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you verify that `Mix_LoadMUS()` is returning a non-NULL `Mix_Music*`?  The [`Mix_PlayMusic()` docs](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC57) don't say anything about handling NULL `music` arguments gracefully.  Ditto for your `IMG_Load()` call.

Comment: @genpfault good thinking. I've added null-checks for pTexture before destroying and after creating, and in Mix_LoadMUS. I've also asserted for zero in Mix_PlayMusic. None of those asserts fail. And it's worth noting that until the crash, the music plays as expected.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for double-checking that & updating the MCVE!  Next up: did you build SDL2, SDL_mixer, & SDL_image with your compiler of choice (I'm guessing a recent-vintage Visual Studio?) or are you using the binaries from libsdl.org?  If you're using the binaries, try building them locally in Debug or RelWithDebInfo mode, that'll make your backtraces muuuuuuch more comprehensible.  Another thing to try is adding a `SDL_PumpEvents()` to your `while` loop.  Sorry I don't have anything better, what you have looks OK to me :(

Comment: To answer your questions: I have been using binaries from libsdl.org, and I'm using VS 2015.

After your comment, I started working on building the relevant SDL libraries in my project from source, and while working at that I had a thought to just update the pre-build libs and see if that had any impact. The result is in the answer below.

Thank you very much for your help. I know you feel you didn't do much, but trying to answer your questions and follow your advice did end up solving my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be to update to the latest version of SDL (2.0.3 -> 2.0.5).

I started developing the project in question with an engine code base which I upgraded from SDL 1.2 to 2.0 about 2 years ago, when the latest version was 2.0.3.

When I recently added sound and music, I took the latest `SDL_mixer`, and didn't think to update SDL to the latest 2.0.5.

After getting the latest development and runtime libraries for SDL (and `SDL_image` and `SDL_mixer` for good measure), the problem disappeared.

I'm not entirely satisfied with this. I'm quite surprised that the newer `SDL_mixer` linked successfully with an older SDL, if they were not compatible. In addition, I can't find any resources online that suggest any compatibility issues. Therefore, I have an uneasy feeling there may have been something else going on, which was resolved incidentally by the upgrade.